# Setting multiple cookies for open-uri

Tags: ruby, cookies, open-uri

I am trying to figure out how I would go about using `['set-cookie']` to add multiple cookies to the request for the web page. If I had the cookies in an array as such:

```
cookie1 = {'domain': 'Website', 'name': 'xyz', 'value': 'ASH', 'path': '/', 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': False}

cookie2 = {'domain': 'Website', 'name': 'xyz', 'value': 'ASH', 'path': '/', 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': False}


page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("a webpage"), "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36", "Cookie" => cookie1['set-cookie'] cookie2['set-cookie'])
```

I have been struggling to find any documentation on how this would integrate into open-uri.

Comment: `set-cookie` is a response header typically used in `POST` requests. `open-uri` can only do `GET` requests. Use `net-http` library instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the cookies with semicolons:

```rb
cookies = cookie1,cookie2].map{|c| c.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('; ')}.join('; ')
open(..., "Cookie" => cookies)
```